# angular2 lite-server change localhost:3000 to myapp.dev:8000

Tags: angular, lite-server

I want to change default browsersync host from localhost:3000 to myapp.dev:8000.

I created a bs-config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    "port": 8000,
    "server": { "baseDir": "./" },
};
```

Port is changed to 8000, but I don't know how can I change the host. Can you help me?

Comment: Why would you change the host? Your local machine is always `localhost`.

Comment: I want to test server part, and I want separete my partners by subdomain

Comment: ..and request come from partner1.myapp.mysoftware.com I will be know, what partner send the request.

Answer (score 0):

You should add [`proxy`](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-proxy) option to `bs-config`.

```
// Using a vhost-based url
proxy: "myapp.dev:8000"
```

Comment: I tried but error happened: npm run lite exited with code 1